# Nested Django tags

Tags: python, django, django-templates, qr-code

I am using the QR code (Django) library and when I do `{% qrcode_from_text "{% url 'foo' %}" "l" %}`, the inner tag gives error. Is there any way to do such nested django template tags? Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, but you don't need to. The `url` tag has a syntax to save the result to a variable:

```
{% url 'foo' as foo_url %}
```

and you can then use that in your custom tag:

```
{% qrcode_from_text foo_url %}
```