# django {%url%} for {%include%}

Tags: django, django-templates

When I try to render this template:

```
{% include "mylistitem.html" with text="foo" btn_text="bar" href="{% url 'register' %}" %}
```

It generates the following error:

> TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '"{%' from '"{%'

Nowhere in the docs I found that expressions couldn"t be nested. 
How could I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe you can nest template tags.

A solution to your current problem would be doing this:

```
{% url 'register' as register_url %}
{% include "mylistitem.html" with text="foo" btn_text="bar" href=register_url  %}
```

This is a duplicate question: [Nested Django tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545628/nested-django-tags)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this all in a single step, you can use two steps:

```
{% url 'register' as some_var %}
{% include "mylistitem.html" with text="foo" btn_text="bar" href=some_var %}
```

We here thus first assign the result of the `{% url ... %}` template tag to a variable (here named `some_var`), and then call the `{% include ... %}` with that variable.

This behavior is documented in the [documentation on the **`url`** template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url):

> (...)
>
> If you'd like to **retrieve a URL without displaying it**, you can use
>   a slightly different call:
>
> ```
> {% url 'some-url-name' arg arg2 as the_url %}
> <a href="{{ the_url }}">I'm linking to {{ the_url }}</a>
> ```